# Event listener for inbox of second account

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to create an event listener:

- I have two accounts on my Outlook session.
- I want to monitor account (2) for new emails.
- When a new email is received in the inbox of account (2), I want to copy the email's subject & body and send it to another person.

I tried something similar to:

```
For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts

    If oAccount = "fakeemail@outlook.com" Then
```

Comment: For non-default folder try ItemAdd. You will need to know how to reference a non-default folder. Search and you will find many results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You will need to access your second account by folder name via [Application.Session.Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-session-property-outlook)*

*[GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220100(v=office.11).aspx) will not work for other stores, or mailboxes.*

*Or you could use `For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts` to get the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220100(v=office.11).aspx) but if you already know the account name **`fakeemail@outlook.com`** then not use it.*

*Example*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.Folder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.Folders("fakeemail@outlook.com") _
                    .Folders("Inbox")
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then
        Debug.Print Item.Subject
    End If    
End Sub
```

***FYI Code goes to `ThisOutlookSession`***